# Regular Expressions - Match Character Not Between Two Strings

Tags: java, regex

I've read many questions that ask about finding a regular expression to match characters between two strings, but my problem is the inverse.  I'm attempting to create an expression that will match characters **NOT** between two strings.

Consider the following string.

```
This is short & [tag]fun & interesting[/tag].
```

I want to replace any ampersand character that is **NOT** inside the tag elements with the symbol @.  The result should be as shown below.

```
This is short @ [tag]fun & interesting[/tag].
```

I tried the following regular expression, but unfortunately, it matches the ampersand inside the tag elements.

```
/(?<!\[tag\])&(?!\[\/tag\])/g
```

I understand that it matches that ampersand because it's surrounded by characters on either side in the string.  But I can't add a random number of characters to check because the lookbehind and lookahead must be fixed length.

Is there a regular expression that will accomplish what I want here?

Comment: No, regex is unsuitable for this. You should also indicate which precise regex dialect you are using -- the slashes look like maybe you are asking about PHP but does it have `/g`? A proper programming language will let you easily solve this by other means (split the string into a list, only perform replacement the elements of the list which are not between two tag elements).

Comment: You could take another approach to this, Find all your `&` that are between the tag elements, replace them with some unique string that is not going to showup in your text. replace remaining `&` with `@` then replace all instances of the unique string with `&`

Comment: Also as a request, can you add some more example strings ? I may have a possible regex pattern, but I will need some more examples to verify it.

Comment: @KaranShishoo Ultimately, I decided to use a variation of your suggestion.  In my Java app, I replace all of the ampersands with &amp;.  Then, I use the regular expression /((\[tag\])(.*?)(\[\/tag\]))/g to get all of the [tag]..[/tag] elements and text inside the tags and replace the &amp; string with &.  That was much easier than trying to build a complicated regular expression to solve the issue.

Comment: @tripleee Thank you for the suggestion.  It was more easily solved in my Java code.  See my other comment to Karan Shishoo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does the job even with nested tag:

- Find: `\[(\w+)\].+?\[/\1\](*SKIP)(*FAIL)|&`
- Replace: `@`

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/Gc4JNe/1)

**How it works:**

- `\[(\w+)\].+?\[/\1\]` is trying to match opening and closing tag with some data inside
- `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` if tag is found, then discard it
- `|` else
- `&` match an ampersand. At this point, we are sure it is not inside a tag.

*Unfortunately this doesn't work with Java, but this requirement was only added after I answered.*

Comment: I should have specified that this regular expression needed to be used in Java code.  Java does not recognize the (*SKIP) and (*FAIL) tokens in the Pattern class.  I resorted to using some additional Java classes and a simpler regular expression to achieve what I needed.  However, your solution works great using the PHP flavor.  Therefore, I'm accepting this answer as others may find it useful.